# angular chart.js multiple chart is not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I create 2 line chart consume data from a $http service. when data resolve only one chart is rendering and the other one is stuck animating in the middle until I hover on then it rendered.

they work if I used $timeout

```
DataApi.chart('api/getInfo/oms_anual_sale').then(function(re){
  $scope.data = re[0];
  $scope.labels = re[1];
  $scope.series= re[2];
});


$timeout(function(){
  DataApi.chart('api/getInfo/oms_monthly_compare').then(function(data){
  $scope.data1 = data[0];
  $scope.labels1 = data[1];
  $scope.series1 = data[2];
  console.log(data[0])
  });
},500);
```

what happen with chart directive?

Comment: Create a plunker.  But guessing from my chart experience it really depends on how and when the data is added to the chart with respect to when the data is available.  Many charting libraries, especially if they are jquery hacks into Angular required the dom element to exist before rendering correctly, so you may have ng-if statements on the element that is the container for the chart, which becomes true and chart data is attempted to load, but in the non-Angular context this element is yet to surface because you haven't had a digest loop yet.  Hence my most of the time it works in a $timeout.

Comment: [PlnKr](https://plnkr.co/edit/963v0VmsGyCGPpf3xmcx?p=preview) here is my plnkr. Note: I use json array instead of data from $http service. by put $timeout at same time one work but other one work only on mouse hover. time slicely different rendering halfway.

Comment: They both seem to work for me.  Looking at the code (awesome Plunker BTW) it looks like the $timeout is needed.  As with many charts the DOM element is needed ``<canvas id="line"`` and ``<canvas id="line1"`` before you can apply the charting code.

Comment: `scope.$watch('series', resetChart, true);`
          `scope.$watch('labels', resetChart, true);`
      `scope.$watch('options', resetChart, true);`
          `scope.$watch('colours', resetChart, true);` comment above codes in chart directive solve my issue. But I don't know if it affects other functionality.